# GPO user script on Win7 doesn't seem to get executed

Tags: group-policy, scripting, logon-scripts

We recently implemented outlook signature distribution software that requires a script to be run, but because this script has a password in plaintext I decided to convert the script to a .exe file (not the safest, but our users won't understand this, besides theres nothing they can do with the database it gives access to).

The problem is that, as far as I can tell, this script does not get executed on the couple of Windows 7 machines that we have. I assume it has something to do with user rights. Running as the computer account won't work, because the script checks which users executes it and then fetches the outlook signature for that user.

Is there any alternative, or a way to force this script to run? Our users obviously don't have administrator rights.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the "Resultant Set of Policy" to check whether or not the policy is being executed?

Info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346858.aspx

It will tell you what is, or isn't being executed.

Comment: I ran gpresult and the GPO is definately active for these users.

Comment: Can you run the exe as the user, on one of the machines that is having issues? Does that work?